# Does OTP gen_server intercept received messages

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am using OTP's gen_server. Can I use a function which sends a message to some process and receives the response? My worry is that this response message would be intercepted by get_server and therefore processed by handle_info instead of by my function.

If I want to have such function, how do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a `receive` expression within one of the gen_server callback functions, it will not be interrupted.  It would however receive messages meant for the `gen_server` itself, so you may want to use a very specific pattern in order to leave other messages in the process mailbox for later processing.

Note that this would make the gen_server process unresponsive to other calls while waiting for the response message.